# Select many-to-many relation with "owns" column

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I put my efforts to solve following problem:
I have 2 tables in my database:
videos and users_videos as pivot between videos and users (i receive user_id from token, so users table is in another db)

Having an user id, i want to select all videos and attach column containing true or false whether user owns a video.

So far i realized this with following query:

```
 SELECT v.*, TRUE AS has_video FROM users_videos AS uv
 RIGHT JOIN videos AS v
 ON uv.video_id = v.id 
 WHERE (uv.user_id = 1)
 UNION
 (
    SELECT v.*, FALSE AS has_video FROM videos AS v

    EXCEPT

    SELECT v.*, FALSE AS has_video FROM users_videos AS uv
    RIGHT JOIN videos AS v
    ON uv.video_id = v.id 
    WHERE (uv.user_id = 1) 
  )
```

Although it selects all videos 3 times. Is there any more optimal solution for such kind of problems?

@EDIT ---

Tables structure

```
users_videos:
id integer
user_id integer
video_id integer

videos:
id: integer
title: string
```

Example data:

users_videos

```
| id | user_id | video_id 
-------------------------
  1    1          1
```

videos

```
| id | title   | 
----------------
  1  | Example 1  
-----------------   
  2  | Example 2  
-----------------
```

Desired result:

```
| id | title      | has_video
------------------------------
  1  | Example 1  |   true
------------------------------   
  2  | Example 2  |   false
------------------------------
```

@UPDATE --

Used @Stefano Zanini approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        v.*,
        CASE
            WHEN uv.user_id IS NULL OR uv.user_id <> 1 THEN FALSE
            ELSE TRUE
        END has_video
FROM    videos v
LEFT JOIN
        users_videos uv
ON      uv.video_id = v.id
```

But one more question came to my mind:

What if i want to display videos in specific category?
Let's say it's another many to many relation on

videos and categories tables with pivot videos_categories

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: Those RIGHT JOINs executes as regular INNER JOINs...

Comment: Updated with sample data and structure

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Do you mean filtering the results for a specific category? Or showing all the categories of each video?

Comment: Filtering results for a specific category @StefanoZanini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without the `UNION` and `EXCEPT` like this

```
select distinct
        v.*,
        case
            when uv.user_id is null or uv.user_id <> 1 then false
            else true
        end has_video
from    videos v
left join
        user_videos uv
on      uv.video_id = v.id
```

Since you described this as a `many-to-many` relationship, more than one user can own the same video, hence the need for `distinct`.

The swap from `right` to `left` join is just because I think it's easier to read.

**Edit**

To filter the results on a specific category (as per question edit) you can add a couple of `join` and a condition in the `where`

```
select distinct
        v.*,
        case
            when uv.user_id is null or uv.user_id <> 1 then false
            else true
        end has_video
from    videos v
join    videos_categories vc
on      v.id = vc.video_id
join    categories c
on      vc.category_id = c.id
left join
        user_videos uv
on      uv.video_id = v.id
where   c.category = 'someCategory'
```

Comment: @StefanoZanini i have updated my question, could u take a look?

Comment: Edited with improved solution

Comment: Thank you @StefanoZanini :)

Answer (score -1):

You want to select all videos and say for each video whether user 1 owns it. So select from videos and look up the user's videos:

```
select 
  v.*,
  id in (select video_id from users_videos where user_id = 1) as has_video
from videos v;
```